# Get value inside list in series of conditions

Tags: python, indexing, conditional-statements

Assuming you have the following code:

```
if "walk" in myList or "run" in myList or "fly" in myList:
    print("You "+dosomething()+" to the chamber on the left")
```

How can you find out which value returned true in the conditions and then print the value, assuming only one condition will return as true?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as follows:

```
for action in ('walk', 'run', 'fly'):
    if action in myList:
        print("You {} to the chamber on the left.".format(action))
        break
```

The `break` will stop the `for` loop once one of the actions is found, so whichever is first will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Convert mylist to a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and use a [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection)

```
myset = set(mylist)

hay = {"walk","run","fly"}
check = hay & myset
if check:
    check = check.pop()
    # Do something with check
```

**Note** This will work as long as your assumption stays correct  `assuming only one condition will return as true`

Comment: You could shorten this code with `if {'walk', 'run', 'fly'}.intersection(mylist):`, but it will certainly be more efficient than my loop

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes I know, but For the above if its a repetitive code it might have an unnecessary overhead to create the set each time it encounters the statement.

Comment: good point. I think Python optimises out set literals in those cases, but I can't remember where I read that...